# How arraylist increase its size internally?

Tags: .net

can someone please explain me how internally array list working? I mean to ask how exactly 
array list increasing length and adding new item.How internally it works? I want an explanation how internally array list increasing length and adding new item.

Comment: `ArrayList` is just part of the .NET framework. It has nothing to do with ASP.NET particularly. As for the internals: there's just a private variable which maintains a reference to an array. When the array needs to be bigger to accommodate new elements, a new array is created, the existing contents copied into it, and the variable reassigned to refer to the new array instead of the old one. Note that in modern code you'd be more likely to use `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arraylist

Comment: That's fine we can use List<T> instead of Array-List but As we know Array-list length is not fixed we can add items as much as we want. But when we are adding items into Array-List Some where in memory its saving those values.I want to know how its increasing its length automatically . In array we are defining its length and its taking that much length only if we are trying to add more then that its showing out of memory error. But In Array-List we never see such error.. Why And How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, `ArrayList` (obviously) uses an array to store values. The same happens to be true for `List<T>`.

If you look at the private method `EnsureCapacity(int)` of `ArrayList` (and `List<T>`), you'll see that, when the `ArrayList` is not big enough to hold the next item, a new internal array is allocated that is double the size of the previous one. After doing this, the contents of the smaller array get copied to the new array.

These are all implementation details though and you can't be sure that every implementation does it the same way (i guess).

Anyway you should use `List<T>` in this case. It works just the same way as ArrayList, but you also have type safety.